# Preprocessing with SMOTE - a following series of binary classifiers result in exact same accuracy, precision, recall and F1 scores

Tags: python, classification, smote

The question here is whether there is a problem here - have you ever had a series of binary classifiers output the exact same performance metrics post SMOTE without this being an error of some sorts.

Note - I also have a couple of classifiers that result in differing performance metrics, though not by much.

Also - this is a small dataset of 395 instances.

Comment: Can you please mention the number of features and the ratio of the 2 classes. I have seen a similar performance but my dataset had 400 samples but **2300** features!

Comment: My dataset has only 46 features

Comment: This you can attribute the results to the **small dataset size**. I used a variety of classifiers from Logistic Regression to KNN to Adaboost to XGBoost. Still, the f1 metric and accuracy came in the range of 0.65-0.7 for all of them. Probably, that is the reason!

Comment: @RaviPrakash I just found this paper where the author gets near exact same results using different algos on small datasets https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/11/2/796 (see table)